# How do I use different versions of pandas with PySpark and spark-submit?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

One can write PySpark code and use `spark-submit` in the following ways:

1. Submit a `.py` file: `spark-submit hello.py`
2. Submit an egg or zip file with `--py-files` and driver file: `spark-submit --py-files hello.egg driver.py`, where `driver.py` calls functions in the `hello` package

For this to work locally the packages in the egg's `requirements.txt` file and those in `driver.py` would need to have been installed on the local machine.

But what about on a spark cluster? The egg doesn't contain the actual dependences; it only contains info on what packages need to be there. If you are using a non-standard library, like pandas, then you need to install those packages on the cluster with `pip`.

I want to use different versions of pandas -- `0.24.2` and `0.25.0` -- in different submissions to the same cluster. Installing pandas locally across the cluster and then replacing it with another version doesn't seem ideal. Is there a clean way to do this with virtual environments?